# JQuery can't select the value from input that created dynamically

Tags: jquery

What I want to do is to add multiple inputs into this div which has id "addedRoles". It first like this:

```
<div id="addedRoles" class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="addedRole form-control" type="text" name="newRoleNames" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And I added more divs using these codes:

```
$('#btnAddNewRole').click(function (event) {
            $('#addedRoles').append(
                '<div class="col-md-10">'
                + '<input class="addedRole form-control" type="text" name="newRoleNames" />'
                + '</div>');
        });
```

After that, I was trying to select values from all inputs but all I got is the value from the first hardcode input. Is it because the inputs were created dynamically?  How to get value from them all? Thanks

Comment: How do you select values from all inputs?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this part. I tried to select all inputs with their name attribute "newRoleNames", their class "addedRole" and all children of "#addedRoles" but they didn't work. All value I got is from the first hardcode input.

Comment: Input should have unique name attribute.

Comment: @Mohammad Not necessarily. `id` has to be unique, but name can be used to pair similar elements and fetch them using name attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically added element .click() doesn't fire. Plus add some class to your textbox. Id should be unique throughout the DOM.

For dynamically added element you should .on in either way.

```
$(document).on('click','.txtboxClass',function (e) 
{
  //do stuff here
  var userInput = $(this).val();
});
```

OR

```
  $('.txtboxClass').on('click',function (e) 
 {
  //do stuff here
  var userInput = $(this).val();
 });
```

If you find adding class an overhead, thats not a big issue you can do using attribute selector as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the class name "addedRole" to get all value because the "name" attribute must be unique

or

```
$("#addedRoles :text").each(function(i, text){
    var $val = $(text).val();
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I just mentioned it in my comment. It only gave me the value from the hardcode input

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all inputs in the class using below :

```
$("#addedRoles :input").each(function(){
 var input = $(this).val(); 
});
```

Comment: From what I understand, he is adding divs/input dynamically in div `addedRoles` and wants values of those. Which means there's one addedRoles the main div and he can get vaues of all using each

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you retrieving input values like that:

```
$('#addedRoles input').val();
```

But it will return value of first input in matches elements only.
Right way is:

```
var values = [];
$('#addedRoles input').each(function(){
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

[Here's JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2avxd1q4/)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sergey. Please avoid adding duplicate answers

Comment: No worries. I usually refresh before adding answer to make sure its not duplicate as it just clutters the post instead :)